# Using Boost.Json lib in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, json, boost

I have been trying to use new [Boost.Json](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/json/doc/html/index.html) lib that was launched in the latest version of boost 1.75.0. For testing purposes I created an empty VS project and added one file and tried to build it. I added the directory in the project's additional include directory. This is what my source file looks like:

```
#include <boost\json.hpp>

void main(){
return;
}
```

When I compile this I get following error:

```
Error   8   error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation  
C:\Libraries\boost_1_75_0\boost\json\detail\config.hpp  311 1   Project1
Error   5   error C2065: 'T' : undeclared identifier     
C:\Libraries\boost_1_75_0\boost\json\detail\config.hpp  311 1   Project1
Error   7   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 
'boost::json::detail::static_const<T>::value'    
C:\Libraries\boost_1_75_0\boost\json\detail\config.hpp  311 1   Project1
Error   2   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'T'    
C:\Libraries\boost_1_75_0\boost\json\detail\config.hpp  308 1   Project1
Error   4   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'T'    
C:\Libraries\boost_1_75_0\boost\json\detail\config.hpp  311 1   Project1
Error   6   error C2923: 'boost::json::detail::static_const' : 'T' is not a valid template type 
argument for parameter 'T'  C:\Libraries\boost_1_75_0\boost\json\detail\config.hpp  311 1   Project1
Error   1   error C3646: 'noexcept' : unknown override specifier     
C:\Libraries\boost_1_75_0\boost\json\detail\config.hpp  292 1   Project1
Error   3   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    
C:\Libraries\boost_1_75_0\boost\json\detail\config.hpp  308 1   Project1
```

Just to verify if I included the boost lib right, I wrote another code

```
#include <boost\property_tree\json_parser.hpp>

void main(){
return;
}
```

and it compiled fine. The reason I want to use json lib instead of property trees is because I want to retain the data type of the json objects whereas trees parse everything in string. Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you compile boost with VS 2013? You can't use binaries from any other version of Visual Studio or even mingw

Comment: Visual Studio 2013? It is badly outdated. It doesn't even support C++11. I highly doubt that latest boost compiles on it.

Comment: You should look at and post the errors in the compiler output window not the errors list, there is generally a lot more context there

Comment: @drescherjm I didn't compile it, most of the lib worked without compiling. Let me try compiling it and will update here if any progress made. Thanks

Comment: Vs 2013 (12) is not on the list of supported compilers https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/json/doc/html/json/overview.html#json.overview.supported_compilers

Comment: @AlanBirtles oh yes, I wasted a whole day trying to fix the error. I have a follow up, even if I compile the the lib using msvs19 will I be able to use the library in vs2013 ?

Comment: No, you can't mix visual studio versions with libraries with c++ interfaces

Comment: Libraries produced with Visual Studio 2015 to 2019 are binary compatible but not compatible with any other version of Visual Studio: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-160](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-160)

Comment: @drescherjm you can use Boost JSON header-onclude (just include the `src.hpp` somewhere). Maybe VS2013 doesn't do the C++11 requirements

Answer (score 0):

Boost.JSON is not tested to compile with Visual Studio 2013. I doubt that it could ever work, as that version of the IDE and compiler does not support C++11 sufficiently for the library.